# How can I get node's memory with kubernetes-client lib in python

Tags: python, kubernetes

Could not find how can I obtain information about memory consumption on kubernetes node with kubernetes-client library in Python. I know how to obtain this information with `kubectl` command.

Could you provide me with a piece of code how can I do this via the lib?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long investigation and some good advice (use `--v=10` flag in `kubectl` command) from the kubernetes-client repository on GitHub I managed to find two resources where I can fetch CPU/memory consumption metrics that I was interested in:

```
https://your.kube-url.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:heapster:/proxy/apis/metrics/v1alpha1/namespaces/default/pods
https://your.kube-url.com/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/http:heapster:/proxy/apis/metrics/v1alpha1/nodes
```

I couldn't find any code examples how to do the same with `kubernetes-client` library that is why will build my own wrappers.

Answer (score 1):

## Getting started

[kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/README.md) contains pieces of code that you need:

```py
from kubernetes import client, config


def main():
    # Configs can be set in Configuration class directly or using helper
    # utility. If no argument provided, the config will be loaded from
    # default location.
    config.load_kube_config()

    v1 = client.CoreV1Api()
    print("Listing pods with their IPs:")
    ret = v1.list_pod_for_all_namespaces(watch=False)
    for i in ret.items:

        print("%s\t%s\t%s" %
              (i.status.pod_ip, i.metadata.namespace, i.metadata.name))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

## Method

For get pod metrics, try this **beta** class:
[V2beta2PodsMetricStatus](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V2beta2PodsMetricStatus.md)

## Metrics

According to [`k8s` documentation](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics/blob/master/docs/pod-metrics.md) Your metrics supposed to be:

- `kube_pod_container_resource_limits_memory_bytes`
- `kube_pod_container_resource_requests_memory_bytes`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yasen. This is where I have issues using V2beta2PodsMetricStatus class. I cannot find any code how to get this info.

Comment: You are right. Since it in beta, there are neither [examples](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/tree/master/examples) nor [tests](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/c4883541465fe6a276365bb3e3dfee34c4e0c296/kubernetes/test/test_v2beta2_pods_metric_status.py) for the `V2beta2PodsMetricStatus` metod

Comment: This seems to be explaining pods memory usage, not a nodes memory usage.  What if a node has multiple pods?

Answer (score 1):

Belated answer, but since this frustrated me so much and I wished there had been a proper answer to this question so I didn't have to go digging for it I'm writing one now to make it easier on the next poor sap.

Here is how you can get memory for nodes:

```
from kubernetes import client

custom_api = client.CustomObjectsApi(client.ApiClient()) 
response = custom_api.list_cluster_custom_object("metrics.k8s.io", "v1beta1", "nodes")

 for node in response['items'];
     print(f"node {node['metadata']['name']} has available memory of {node['usage']['memory']}")
```

If you get an unauthorized response when you try to run this your need to update your clusterRole and clusterRoleBinding to authorize this.